# bad_lexical_cast Exception handling in c++

Tags: c++11

i am using lexical cast in a function for three different variables. Now if a bad_lexical_cast exception occurs i have to set default values respective to each variable. now how to find from which statement the exception  is thrown?

Comment: Look at 6.2 example [from](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.lexical_cast). Do the same, put each call of *lexical_cast* into `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the default values first and then wrap each `boost::lexical_cast` into a `try-catch` block.

Or, better, extract a function that does it for you:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class S>
T lexical_cast_or_default(S s, T default_value) noexcept {
    T value;
    return boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert(s, value)
        ? value
        : default_value
        ;
}

int main() {
    double a = lexical_cast_or_default("abc", 3.14);
    double b = lexical_cast_or_default("123", 3.14);
    int c = lexical_cast_or_default<int>("456", 3.14);
    std::cout << a << '\n';
    std::cout << b << '\n';
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
3.14
123
456
```